# omni auth rails gem ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, foursquare

I'm getting the error message "ArgumentError - ActionController: Exception Caught"

```
wrong number of arguments (6 for 5)

lib/omniauth/strategies/foursquare.rb:19:in `initialize'
lib/omniauth/strategies/foursquare.rb:19:in `initialize'
```

I'm having trouble understanding where there are 6 vs 5 arguments and what I need to modify:

```
def initialize(app, consumer_key = nil, consumer_secret = nil, options = {}, &block)
client_options = {:site => 'http://foursquare.com'}

auth_path = (options[:sign_in] == false) ? '/oauth/authorize' : '/oauth/authenticate'
auth_path = "/mobile#{auth_path}" if options[:mobile]

client_options[:authorize_path] = auth_path

super(app, :foursquare, consumer_key, consumer_secret, client_options, &block)
end
```

my # config/initializers/omniauth.rb contains:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
              provider :foursquare, '[key1]', '[key2]'
 end
```

What should I modify to get only 5 arguments for 5? This is specific to the implementation of the Foursquare Omniauth Strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `super` contains 6 arguments (`:foursquare` between `app` and `consumer_key` is new). The constructor of the class you're inheriting from should tell you what arguments to pass.